# Implement Laravel/AJAX search bar

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, searchbar

Hello I can do a standard AJAX/PHP search but finding it hard to convert to Laravel. I'm using key up instead of button click. I'm not sure if this is the right way im going about to implement an ajax/laravel search bar. I'm looking to output the database data into the div in the view page, but need help on going about this. If anyone thinks im doing this wrong please advise me. Always willing to learn new code.

Controller:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Patient;

use DB;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PatientController extends Controller
{


public function search(Request $request) {
    // get the search term
    $text = $request->input('text');

    // search the members table
    $patients = DB::table('patients')->where('firstname', 'Like', $text)->get();


    // return the results
    return response()->json($patients);
}

}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('search', 'PatientController@search');
```

View:

```
   @extends('Layout.master')


@section('content')


  <!-- Ajax code -->

       <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


    <script type="application/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){

        $('#txtSearch').on('keyup', function(){

            var text = $('#txtSearch').val();

            $.ajax({

                type:"GET",
                url: '127.0.0.1:8000/search',
                data: {text: $('#txtSearch').val()},
                success: function(data) {

                    console.log(data);

                 }



            });


        });

    });
    </script>

    <div style="margin-top:70px;"></div>


       @include('partials._side')

    <div class="container">

                     <form method="get" action="">

                    <div class="input-group stylish-input-group">
                        <input type="text" id="txtSearch" name="txtSearch" class="form-control"  placeholder="Search..." >
                        <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <button type="submit">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
                            </button>  
                        </span>
                    </div>

                     </form> 


          <div id="result"></div>

</div>

@endsection
```

Comment: Yes! I got so close. Now I am getting an error message of this from console.log - SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'open' on 'XMLHttpRequest': Invalid URL

Comment: I'm getting success does this mean all my code works?

Comment: Now to output the data hmmm lol

Comment: please comment below [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41771251/1880431)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `AJAX` request change:

```
'127.0.0.1:8000/search'
```

to

```
'/search'
```

I suggest you to use [**jQuery Autocomplete**](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Very easy to set up.

[Check out the API documentation.](http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: He might not want to load the entire list of patients onto the client computer for this to function.

Comment: you don't have to, it could be an ajax request to a laravel endpoint

Comment: Which doesn't really solve his problem as he is having difficulty getting Laravel to respond in the first place....

Comment: @MattAltepeter OP never said what is not working, how can I guess

Comment: @steven ok great!

Comment: @meda If i want to output a table with data will i need to put the table in the Patientcontroller page?

Comment: once you get the data you can create table with javascript

Comment: like to access the data in the view -  do i touch this --   // return the results
    return response()->json($patients);

Comment: @meda wrong example lol i don't need javascript for this :? no other simpler ways?

Comment: what do you mean you are using ajax, thats javascript

Comment: yeah but can i not create with html? and use laravel foreach loop to loop through the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133683/discussion-between-meda-and-steven).

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your version of Laravel (new versions use this):

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function search(Request $request) {
    $text = $request->input('text');

    $patients = DB::table('patients')->where('firstname', 'Like', "$text")->get();

    return response()->json($patients);
}
```

And then in javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#txtSearch').on('keyup', function(){

        var text = $('#txtSearch').val();

        $.ajax({

            type:"GET",
            url: 'search',
            data: {text: $('#txtSearch').val()},
            success: function(response) {
                 response = JSON.parse(response);
                 for (var patient of response) {
                     console.log(patient);
                 }
             }



        });


    });

});
```

https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/requests#retrieving-input.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/133685/discussion-on-answer-by-matt-altepeter-implement-laravel-ajax-search-bar).

Answer (score 0):

If you mean handle result in browser, please check inside your AJAX coded with jQuery, "response" variable is the server coming back data. 
You just need to populate the returned data into your page after AJAX finished.

For example put into

```
<div id="searchResult"></div>
```

You need put below inside your ajax after response coming back with jquery like:

```
$("#searchResult").html(response);
```

Comment: So you think I'm going in the right direction with the above code if i fix that mistake u point out?

Comment: Yes, it work this way. Unless server return nothing.

Comment: return response()->($patients); Is this line of code correct? if im using a mysql database.

Comment: Sorry, I don't use PHP. 
Only can help front-end, try check result return or not ya. Thanks.